# changing text size using Raphael

Tags: jquery, css, raphael, jquery-animate

I copy-pasted this code from my own previous working document, so I know the code is right, but something else must be causing problems. I'm using the Raphael js library to do animation, and I need to add text labels to my animation.

My problem is that when I try to change the text size, the size of the text won't actually change. Even when I open up Firebug, it lists the text as the correct size, but the text renders as the same tiny size that it's not supposed to be every time.

```
var c = paper.text(xR-Math.cos(.8)*letterOffset, yR-Math.sin(.8)*letterOffset, "c.").attr({fill: '#737373', 'font-family': 'IM Fell DW Pica'});
var m = paper.text(xG+Math.cos(5*Math.PI/4)*letterOffset, yG-Math.sin(5*Math.PI/4)*letterOffset, "m.").attr({fill: '#737373', 'font-family': 'IM Fell DW Pica'});
var s = paper.text(xB+Math.cos(0)*letterOffset, yB-Math.sin(0)*letterOffset, "s.").attr({fill: '#737373', 'font-size': '72px', 'font-family': 'IM Fell DW Pica'});
```

As you can see, one of the letters is set to size 72, but they all render the exact same size. Why won't Raphael change the text size?

You can see the source here:
http://jrstrauss.net/cms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main.css style reset is interfering with the styles set by Raphael:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 12px; //remove this
}
```